$ \sup \{|x_n| \mid n\in \mathbb N \}= \lim_{n\to \infty} (\lim_{p\to \infty}(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^p)^{1/p}) $
I have to prove that for a bounded sequence $ {x_n}$
$$ \sup \{|x_n| \mid n\in \mathbb N \}=  \lim_{n\to \infty} (\lim_{p\to \infty}(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^p)^{1/p}) $$
I know that
$$ \sup \{|x_n| \mid n\in \mathbb N \}=  \lim_{p\to \infty}(\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k|^p)^{1/p}$$
if it is correct to switch the order of these limits, I can ger the desired result directly; Since:
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} (\lim_{n\to \infty}(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^p)^{1/p})=\lim_{p\to \infty} (\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^p)^{1/p} =\lim_{p\to \infty}(\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k|^p)^{1/p}=\sup \{|x_n| \mid n\in \mathbb N \}$$
But is it correct? Can we switch the order of these limits in general? or is there any condition for that?

No need to switch limits. Just apply $ \sup {|x_n| \mid n\in \mathbb N }=  \lim_{p\to \infty}(\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k|^p)^{1/p}$ to finite sums first.

@geetha290krm do you mean like this: $  \lim_{n\to \infty} (\lim_{p\to \infty}(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^p)^{1/p})=\lim_{n\to \infty}(\sup {|x_k| \mid 1 \le k \le n })=\sup {|x_n| \mid n\in \mathbb N } $ is it correct ?

Yes, that is correct.

@geetha290krm thank you very much

Given a bounded sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, in order to try to talk about the expression
$$\lim_{p\to\infty} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_{k}|^{p} \right)^{1/p},$$
you need to know that there is some $p_{0}\in [1, \infty )$ such that whenever $p\in [1, \infty )$ with $p_{0}\leq p$, the series $\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n}|x_{k}|^{p} \right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges. But there exist bounded sequences where this does not occur. Any bounded sequence which does not converge to zero is such an example. So it does not make sense to say that
$$\sup \{|x_{n}| : n\in\mathbb{N} \} = \lim_{p\to\infty} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_{k}|^{p} \right)^{1/p}$$
for a given bounded sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, because the series in the expression does not exist in general.
The first formulation of the question works around this problem. For a fixed bounded sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and a given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the expression $\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}|x_{k}|^{p} \right)^{1/p}$ is defined for any $p\in [1, \infty )$. Then you can attempt to take the limit as $p\to\infty$ to see whether $\lim_{p\to\infty } \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}|x_{k}|^{p} \right)^{1/p}$ exists for the given $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Once it has been shown that this exists for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, you can attempt to take the limit as $n\to\infty$ and see whether this limit exists. You want to show that this limit does exist and that it is equal to $\sup \{|x_{n}| : n\in\mathbb{N} \}$.
Going through all the conditions for the existence of the above limit indicates a method that can be used to prove the statement. You can try to evaluate, given some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the expression $\lim_{p\to\infty } \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}|x_{k}|^{p} \right)^{1/p}$. In fact, you can show that this is equal to $\max \{|x_{k}| : k\in\mathbb{N} , k\leq n \}$. Once you do this, it should be clear that taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ obtains the desired result.
Finally, whenever you want to interchange limits, you need to have a good reason as to why it is valid to do so. You typically require certain assumptions in order to interchange limits for some given equation, and if you do not have such assumptions, you cannot generally swap the limits and obtain the same value, let alone even know if the limits in both expressions exist.

Thank you very much
